NPM Run Build Not Working For NextJS App on AWS But Works on Local Machine
NPM run build is not working for me when I try to install my NextJS app on AWS ubuntu, but works fine on my local machine. I also works fine on Versel. Same exact code.
I'm just installing the basic boiler plate app created by "npx-create-next-app@latest". No additional code. No changes.
Note that all of the errors seems to be related to libraries node_modules, which are all default since I'm just testing out the boiler plate app and didn't add any of my own libraries.
Are there some special settings that need to be applied in production?
Below is an example of errors I'm getting on AWS:
`
Error:  should not be imported outside of pages/_document.
Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-document-import-in-page
at Z (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/pages.runtime.prod.js:16:5430)
at I (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/.next/server/chunks/682.js:6:1263)
at renderWithHooks (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5658:16)
at renderIndeterminateComponent (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5732:15)
at renderElement (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5957:7)
at renderNodeDestructiveImpl (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6115:11)
at renderNodeDestructive (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6087:14)
at finishClassComponent (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5688:3)
at renderClassComponent (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5696:3)
at renderElement (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5954:7)
Error occurred prerendering page "/404". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
Error:  should not be imported outside of pages/document.
Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-document-import-in-page
at Z (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/pages.runtime.prod.js:16:5430)
at I (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/.next/server/chunks/682.js:6:1263)
at renderWithHooks (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5658:16)
at renderIndeterminateComponent (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5732:15)
at renderElement (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5957:7)
at renderNodeDestructiveImpl (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6115:11)
at renderNodeDestructive (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6087:14)
at finishClassComponent (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5688:3)
at renderClassComponent (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5696:3)
at renderElement (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5954:7)
Generating static pages (2/5)  [=   ]TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
at t.useContext (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:109363)
at d (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/.next/server/chunks/892.js:1:21622)
at h (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/.next/server/chunks/892.js:1:13546)
at au (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:10446)
at /home/ubuntu/testnextjs/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:15122
at aw (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:16908)
at a (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:49776)
at ab (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:11808)
at /home/ubuntu/testnextjs/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:16871
at aw (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:16908) {
digest: '2707240633'
}
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
at t.useContext (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:109363)
at d (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/.next/server/chunks/892.js:1:21622)
at h (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/.next/server/chunks/892.js:1:13546)
at au (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:10446)
at /home/ubuntu/testnextjs/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:15122
at aw (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:16908)
at a_ (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:49776)
at ab (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:11808)
at /home/ubuntu/testnextjs/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:16871
at aw (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:16908)
Error occurred prerendering page "/_not-found". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
at t.useContext (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:109363)
at d (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/.next/server/chunks/892.js:1:21622)
at h (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/.next/server/chunks/892.js:1:13546)
at au (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:10446)
at /home/ubuntu/testnextjs/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:15122
at aw (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:16908)
at a_ (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:49776)
at ab (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:11808)
at /home/ubuntu/testnextjs/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:16871
at aw (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:16908)
Error:  should not be imported outside of pages/_document.
Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-document-import-in-page
at Z (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/pages.runtime.prod.js:16:5430)
at I (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/.next/server/chunks/682.js:6:1263)
at renderWithHooks (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5658:16)
at renderIndeterminateComponent (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5732:15)
at renderElement (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5957:7)
at renderNodeDestructiveImpl (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6115:11)
at renderNodeDestructive (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6087:14)
at finishClassComponent (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5688:3)
at renderClassComponent (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5696:3)
at renderElement (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5954:7)
Error occurred prerendering page "/500". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
Error:  should not be imported outside of pages/document.
Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-document-import-in-page
at Z (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/pages.runtime.prod.js:16:5430)
at I (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/.next/server/chunks/682.js:6:1263)
at renderWithHooks (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5658:16)
at renderIndeterminateComponent (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5732:15)
at renderElement (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5957:7)
at renderNodeDestructiveImpl (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6115:11)
at renderNodeDestructive (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6087:14)
at finishClassComponent (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5688:3)
at renderClassComponent (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5696:3)
at renderElement (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5954:7)
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
at t.useContext (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:109363)
at d (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/.next/server/chunks/892.js:1:21622)
at h (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/.next/server/chunks/892.js:1:13546)
at au (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:10446)
at /home/ubuntu/testnextjs/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:15122
at aw (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:16908)
at a (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:49776)
at ab (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:11808)
at /home/ubuntu/testnextjs/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:16871
at aw (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:16908) {
digest: '2707240633'
}
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
at t.useContext (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:109363)
at d (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/.next/server/chunks/892.js:1:21622)
at h (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/.next/server/chunks/892.js:1:13546)
at au (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:10446)
at /home/ubuntu/testnextjs/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:15122
at aw (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:16908)
at a_ (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:49776)
at ab (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:11808)
at /home/ubuntu/testnextjs/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:16871
at aw (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:16908)
Error occurred prerendering page "/". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
at t.useContext (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:109363)
at d (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/.next/server/chunks/892.js:1:21622)
at h (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/.next/server/chunks/892.js:1:13546)
at au (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:10446)
at /home/ubuntu/testnextjs/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:15122
at aw (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:16908)
at a_ (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:49776)
at ab (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:11808)
at /home/ubuntu/testnextjs/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:16871
at aw (/home/ubuntu/testnextjs/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:16908)
✓ Generating static pages (5/5)

Export encountered errors on following paths:
/_error: /404
/_error: /500
/_not-found/page: /_not-found
/page: /

`
I was expecting the build on my AWS server to work exactly like it does on my local machine.
